# angular2 Property 'append' does not exist on type 'Headers'

Tags: angular

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
   export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
      let headers: Headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');}
```

I get the following error for the above code.

> 'append' error: Property 'append' does not exist on type 'Headers'.

How to solve it?

Comment: Put your code `let headers: Headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');` within `constructor` or `ngOnInit()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead.

```
import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Headers, Http} from '@angular/http';

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{

  public headers: Headers;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
  }
}
```